# Reloading file when modified

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can reload a local file when it gets modified.

---

My use case: I sometimes use Google Chrome to view pictures or PDFs. Those files sometimes get modified and I would like from to automatically reload them.

Comment: You could look into [LivePage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livepage/pilnojpmdoofaelbinaeodfpjheijkbh?hl=en) - it is works for local JS/CSS/HTML/LESS but not for images but it *might* be easy to edit to allow that.